# How to make dynamic submenu also clickable from drowdown Antd library in React App?

Tags: create-react-app, antd

This is the current way I am loading Menu items:

`import { Menu, Dropdown, Button, message, Tooltip } from 'antd';`

```
    const items = [
        { label: 'item 1 label', key: 'item-1' },
        { label: 'item 2 label', key: 'item-2', disabled:false }, 
        { label: 'item 4 label', key: 'item-4', disabled:false, icon: null, children: null }, 
        {
          label: 'sub menu',
          key: 'submenu',
          icon: <ApartmentOutlined />,
          children: [{ label: 'item 3', key: 'submenu-item-1' }]
        },
      ];

  const menu = (
        <Menu items={items} onClick={this.handleMenuClick}>  
        </Menu>
      );
```

However under the node that has children I cannot place an onClick property.
Any way to make any submenu or object with children, also clickable or to trigger a function?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by using as a property.

````
              onTitleClick: () => alert("HELLO WORLD")```
````